# Can I ask about why you don't travel to ...?

Tags: discussion, scope

Can I ask questions like

- why you don't travel to ...?
- what do you think about traveling to ... country?

etc.

Answer (score 8):

Please don't ask questions like that, they're exactly the ones mentioned in the Help Center article [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](/help/dont-ask):

> **To prevent your question from being flagged [and possibly removed](https://travel.stackexchange.com/helpcenter/deleted-questions), avoid asking subjective questions where ...**
>
> - every answer is equally valid: “What’s your favorite ______?”

From the same page:

> You should only ask practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face. Chatty, open-ended questions diminish the usefulness of our site and push other questions off the front page.